# Cmder command line issue

Tags: command-line, cmder

I have an issue in Cmder: when I type the `touch` command in the command line then it displays the following error message ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agbox.png)):

> 'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: what is the version of your cmder? try updating your cmder,

Answer (score 0):

You Must Install **touch**

```
npm install touch-cli -g
```